# Move applications and DB to docker or vm

Tags: virtualization, proxmox, containers, docker-machine

I have one server with one public IP.

- Apache2 is installed.
- Mariadb is installed.
- There are about 50 identical Java applications running on Tomcat on
  the server.
- The applications are running on some port, and Apache has a reverse
  proxy, so when the appropriate www address is entered, the
  redirection to the port of the respective application is made.

The structure looks something like this:
/apps/
directory Application1..n in this directory subdirectories
-tomcat
-lib (openjdk)
-files - files that are uploaded to the application (.pdf, jpg, txt, xls) and files generated by the application (.pdf, xls, csv)
-logs

Each such application has its own database.
Every day, a backup of the database and a backup of the files directory is made and moved to another location.
Every month, updates are performed, including: updating the database structure (the programmers receive an SQL file that I run on each database), updating the application by uploading a new *.war file, replacing the tomcat directory (updating Tomcat), and replacing the lib directory (updating OpenJDK).

I would like to change this so that each application is a separate instance.
Some kind of container or vm , that includes mariadb server,tomcat, openjdk.

I would also like to connect Zabbix to each application instance (monitoring the entire host, as well as MySQL, JXM, etc.).

I'm not sure whether Docker or Proxmox (LXD), OpenVZ would be better. Which one is more practical and easier to maintain in this situation?
Maybe there is other solution ?
Could you give me some advice?

Comment: we can't tell you what product is the best for. it depends on the usecase. if you have the ressources I would prefer a cluster of proxmox with lxd as it has the most less footprint but most flexible with standard administration. docker on the other could a way if you know how to build them. I never used openvz so I can't tell you anything about it